# Sending log files/data from one EC2 instance to another

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash, kibana, filebeat

So i have one EC2 instance with logstash, elastichsearch and kibana installed on it. and i have another EC2 instance thats running a dummy apache server. Now i know that i should install filebeat on the apache server instance to send the log files to the logstash instance but im not sure how to configure the files.

My main goal is to send the log files from one instance basically to another for processing and viewing aka ES and Kibana. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So as you have already stated, the easiest way to send log events from one machine to an Elastic instance is to install the filebeat agent on the machine the apache is running.

Filebeat has its own [Apache module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-apache.html) that makes the configuration even easier! In the module you specify the paths of the desired log files.

Then you also need a [configuration of Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration.html) itself. In the filebeat.yml you need to define the logstash destination under

```
output.logstash
```

[This configuration guide gets into more details](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-howto-filebeat.html)

Take a look at the [filbeat.yml reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-reference-yml.html) on all configuration settings.

If you are familiar with docker, there is also a guide on [how to run filebeat on docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html).

Have fun! :-)

Comment: You don't need Logstash in this setup (actually it will only make it more complicated). Use the Filebeat module for apache and configure the output for Elasticsearch directly. You'll only need Filebeat on the monitored instance and Elasticsearch + Kibana on the other.

Comment: Yes, you can get rid of that for this use-case (especially as a beginner). You‘re adding complexity and resource usage without any advantages. In case you need Logstash [add these extra steps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filebeat-modules.html), but just skip it here :)

Comment: Sorry, but I dont consider your *comments* as helpful. **You can add another answer to give hints/advice.** My answer contains logstash information since the OP presented a use case that includes that component.

Comment: so if i understood your comments correctly, as a beginner i dont need logstash but for prod environments it would be necessary?